# Asymmetric convolutional autoencoder?

Tags: deep-learning, autoencoders

The starting image size is 49x49 and therefore the encoder and decoder parts are not symmetric. Is it going to affect the ability of the network to learn? 
PS - By asymmetric I mean the filter sizes (kernel sizes), strides are not same for the encoder and decoder part of the network.